# Volume of an airfoil

Tags: numerical-methods, definite-integrals, volume

I need to know the volume a NACA 0010 airfoil , because there is nothing on the internet and i am still in high school , i have no clue on how to do it , so i decided that if i had the shape on a graph , i could work out the volume of revolution . i faced another problem , i don't know how to get the equation of the curve. So , i found this site where i got point on the curve ( 100 point to be exact ) . Is there any way to get the equation of that curve using computer ( my brother is in engineering school , so we have matlab) [image] this is my first post here , so i don't really know the right tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have points on the curve tabulated on a computer, then the natural approach would be to approximate the integral numerically using the trapezoidal rule. Fitting with an analytic expression and integrating symbolically would probably introduce larger errors anyway.

---

There are exact equations for NACA airfoils to find [at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NACA_airfoil), though.

Comment: the formulas in wikipedia are used to determine the dimensions of an airfoil. Pardon my ignorance , but isn't trapezium rule used to determine area under graph?

Comment: @Abdelrahman: My understanding is that the formulas on Wikipedia define the red curve on your graph, so you can integrate them symbolically. Yes, the trapezoid sum would give you the area of the cross-section you're showing in the question, which you'd then multiply by the length of the wing to find its volume. I'm a bit confused why you're speaking of volumes of revolution in the question ...

Comment: What i really wanted is the volume of a teardrop shaped body, if I used volume of revolution it will give the volume of a teardrop shaped body , right?

Comment: @Abdelrahman: Okay, but you can still use your table to compute the volume of revolution numerically -- the volume is $\pi\int f(x)^2\,dx$ so if you have a table of $f(x)$s you can add a column with $f(x)^2$s and use the trapezoidal sum to integrate _that_.

Comment: That might work , ty